# Erro ao utilizar o método File.Delete dentro da Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Estou com problemas em minha `controller` no momento em que inicio uma rotina de exclusão de arquivos.

Eu estou utilizando o método `File.Delete()`, porem ele simplesmente não reconhece e me retorna a seguinte advertência:

> Cannot choose method from method group. Did you intend to invoke the method?

**Segue o código também:**

```
public void Delete(String id)
{
    //Função que busca o meu arquivo de delete
    var modelArquivo = BuscaArquivo(id);

    //Aqui se atribue o nome completo do arquivo
    var nomeArquivo = modelArquivo.NomeArquivoCompleto;

    //Aqui da-se a advertência citada acima
    File.Delete(nomeArquivo);         
}
```

Alguma ideia sobre o que está a acontecer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Está me parecendo conflito de `namespace`. Você poderia testar com:

```
System.IO.File.Delete(nomeArquivo)
```

Answer (score 10):

Já tentou usar no lugar de

```
//Aqui da-se a advertência citada acima
File.Delete(nomeArquivo);
```

Usar

```
System.IO.File.Delete(nomeArquivo)
```